# Changing the unit displayed in the x-axes in time series with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I'm starting to use ggplot2 for time series. I need to change the day display unit on the x-axis. It is now set by default to seven days, but I would like to set the label every two days. How can I do? Thanks!!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TBYU.png)

I'm looking for information, but I only find how to set the limits (with expand_limit), instead I need to change the units.

***UPDATED***
I am working with the following dataset: Temperatures of July 2022.

library(readxl)

Tempjuly22 <- read_excel("C:/Users/Tempjuly22.xlsx", + col_types = c("date", "numeric"))

View(Tempjuly22)

str(Tempjuly22$Day)

POSIXct[1:31], format: "2022-07-01" "2022-07-02" "2022-07-03" "2022-07-04" "2022-07-05" ...

library(ggplot2)

list(Tempjuly22)
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuhMP.png)]

Day                 AvgTemp
                
1 2022-07-01 00:00:00    27.0
2 2022-07-02 00:00:00    28.6
3 2022-07-03 00:00:00    29.6
4 2022-07-04 00:00:00    28.8
5 2022-07-05 00:00:00    26.6
6 2022-07-06 00:00:00    26.4
7 2022-07-07 00:00:00    26.6
8 2022-07-08 00:00:00    27.3
9 2022-07-09 00:00:00    28.8
10 2022-07-10 00:00:00    29.7

The simple code I use to generate the graph is:

l = ggplot(Tempjuly22, aes(x =Day, y = AvgTemp)) + geom_line()

That gives:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuhMP.png)

Then, I would like to change the x axes (Day) with 3 days instead of 7 days. I try to use scale_x_date, but it tells me it only works with the "Date" type.

Thanks everyone for the help and the avaibility!

Comment: Check out `help("scale_x_date")`, focus on the documentation of the `date_breaks` argument and look at the examples.

Comment: Thank you, but it think that it does not work in ggplot2

Comment: What does not work in ggplot2? `scale_x_date` is a ggplot2 function. Possibly you need to use `scale_x_datetime` instead. You don't provide any information regarding your data, so I can't know if you are dealing with a variable of class `Date`, `POSIXct`, `POSIXlt` or something else.

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the post with other information. I write the data and the code used. Scale_x_date does not work maybe because I have POSIXct variable?  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: If you have a POSIXct variable, you need to use `scale_x_datetime`.

Comment: Please use `dput(Tempjuly22)` to attach your data to the question.

Comment: I believe you can use `Tempjul22$day <- as.Date(Tempjul22$day)` to cast POSIXct to date.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that this question has already been answered somewhere on SO, but I could not find it. Nonetheless, you might find [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/06/customizing-time-and-date-scales-in-ggplot2/) blog post useful.

To answer your specific question, let's first generate some data:

```
# libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
rnorm(20) -> x
dates <- seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-01')+19, 1)

mydata <- data.frame(bind_cols('date'=dates, 'x'=x))
```

You can set the date labels by `scale_x_date` in ggplot like this:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=date, y=x)) + 
   geom_line() + 
    scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-01')+19, 2) )
```

Output [image: breaks every two days]

If you want, you can also adjust the labels and breaks separately (this is not exactly what you asked, but might still be useful).

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=date, y=x)) + 
   geom_line() + 
    scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-01')+19, 9), 
                 minor_breaks=seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-01')+19, 2))
```

Output:
[image: breaks every two days, labels every 10 days]

Comment: Thank you for the comment, and the useful information. I was looking for the same question but I am not able to find it. I think I have problems with the Date and POSIXct class, because the code I try does not work with my data. I updated the post to be more clearer about the data.